# Relationship field in grid field not outputting data using EE3

Tags: relationships, grid, ee3

I have a relationship field in a grid field which is not outputting any data. But, it should.

```
{service_types}

    <div class="column">

        <a href="{service_types:url:url_title}">
            <img src="{service_types:src}" alt="{service_types:alt_text}">
        </a>

    </div>

{/service_types}
```

`{service_types}` is the grid field and `{service_types:url:url_title}` is the relationship field. This works in EE2, but not EE3 seemingly?

I have checked that the target entries are open and not have silly expired or far future dates etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Right, looks like it has to be in a tag pair.

{service_types}

```
<div class="column">

    <a href="{service_types:url}{service_types:url:url_title}{/service_types:url}">
        <img src="{service_types:src}" alt="{service_types:alt_text}">
    </a>

</div>

{/service_types}
```